# Oracle End To End metrics with Jooq

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jooq

I am working on a batch application where DAO layers uses jooq to interact with the oracle database. I have configured `setClientInfo` to the oracle connection with all the necessary OCSID keys. I am using a wrapper class that extends `DelegatingDataSource` to dynamically change the module, action, ecid & client_id during different stages of the batch application like example i am setting `action` as a current step name and `module` as a current job name and so on. I have also set `action` with procedure names.

I want to track from these metrics that which job/step/procedure is having performance issues. I have observed that during the batch application is running some metrics are saved in `v$session` table. After batch application is completed i can only see some entries in `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`. I have also tried by making procedures sleep for more than 2 mins using  `APEX_UTIL.PAUSE(120)` but i am not able to find all the entries in the `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` table after batch application is run. Even if there are more than 10 to 15 DB calls during the batch application was run, i can only see 3 to 4 entries in `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`. How these metrics are saved in `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`? How can i achieve tracking the performance with respect to the job/step/procedure used in the batch application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by removing APEX_UTIL.PAUSE. After going though this https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/ash/ i understood that if session goes to sleep it will appear in v$session as status = ‘ACTIVE’ and state = ‘WAITING’ but it will not be recorded in v$active_session_history.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your `DataSource` with jOOQ's `DataSourceConnectionProvider`, jOOQ will always call `Connection.close()` at the end of each statement, which might, depending on your configuration, put the connection back in the pool and maybe free some resources. If you want to ensure your "session" lasts longer, make sure the connection pool doesn't free those resources, or even pass a JDBC `Connection` to jOOQ instead of a `DataSource`, in case of which jOOQ will not call `Connection.close()`. You will.

Perhaps, if lower precision sampling is fine with you, you might be more interested in querying `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` instead, see: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/active-session-history

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for the information. But i am still not clear on how the samples are collected every second and stored in V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY view. Consider an example i have a batch application which runs around 5 mins and makes around 10 unique DB calls during this time. I assume after the batch is run i should be able to find all the 10 samples collected either in V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY or DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY? but i can only see some samples but not all.